# Execute only one exists in SQL

Tags: sql, oracle

I'm creating a report with iReport over an Oracle DB. I have to select some values depending on a condition like this:

```
AND EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM TABLE_1 WHERE x = y)  
OR EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM TABLE_2 WHERE z = y)
```

is it possible to execute the second EXISTS only if the first is false?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Try to use your conditions in brackets:

```
AND (
        EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM TABLE_1 WHERE x = y)  
     OR EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM TABLE_2 WHERE z = y)
    )
```

Comment: I've tested this solution on my data vs. the CASE solution. This is the fastest for me. There are also big differences between the cost of the query, this solution has a cost of 3360 (on my query obviously) vs a cost over 100k of the case solution.

Comment: @noizer - Yeah. It's faster and easy to understand. :)

Answer (score 2):

use CASE

```
where 
 ...
 AND 1 = case
          when EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM TABLE_1 WHERE x = y)  then 1
          when EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM TABLE_2 WHERE z = y)  then 1
          else 0
         end
```

Answer (score 0):

```
AND (case when (SELECT count(*) FROM TABLE_1 WHERE x = y) > 0 then true
when (SELECT count(*) FROM TABLE_2 WHERE z = y) > 0 then true 
else false end)
```